# local cache post map reduce jobs taking space

Tags: hadoop, caching, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am using Hortonworks environment for big data processing.

I observed that as part of Map Reduce jobs from Hive/Oozie/Pig etc my below local cache directory is getting filled up.It creates one folder for every map reduce execution with the jar files.

/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/filecache

Is it fine if I delete these folders directly? is there any configuration that I can set to remove it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These directories should be cleaned up automatically every 600000ms (10 minutes).

Or you can reduce this timeperiod by setting up this property in `yarn-site.xml`,
`yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms`.

You can also change the maximum size this cache directory should occupy,
`yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb`. The default target size is 10240MB.

If no jobs are running, manual deletion of cache is fine. Restart nodemanager after deleteing the cache.

Comment: Actually both these entries are not present in my yarn-site.xml file. I will add them and restart yarn services midnight when no users are using the system and once all jobs are also completed. Can i delete the old folders manually and restart node manager?

Comment: Yes, Manual delete is fine. Old cache is not needed once the job is completed.

Comment: I only applied the changes yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms and restarted the yarn and nodemanager services. However the folders did not cleared. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Then I believe your Hadoop version could be affected by this bug [YARN-4540](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4540).

Comment: Deletion of these cache manually is the way if the properties do not work. Set up a script to clear these files automatically when jobs are not running, if the cache directory is filled up to the maximum it leads to the failing of jobs.

Comment: Thanks franklinsijo for the information. I am using HDP 2.4 and ambari version 2.2.1.0 . The bug you mentioned has different versions. I have voted the answer because manual deletion and restarting yarn services help me without impacting the system.

Comment: Hadoop configuration explicitly says these properties do not affect APPLICATION resources:

"Target size of localizer cache in MB, per nodemanager. It is a target retention size that only includes resources with PUBLIC and PRIVATE visibility and excludes resources with APPLICATION visibility"

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

So the properties should have no effect if the cache is filled with APPLICATION resources. I don't know of any way to limit this.